# "Recent Achievements" popup/badge is not updating

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog, live-refresh, caching

I'm not getting real time updates in the achievement icon/popup. Nether the badge showed the green color icon for recent upvotes, nor popup has been updated.

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can confirm this.  I haven't had any updates in about 3-4 hours.  _But_, if I look at the reputation tab of my profile, everything is being reported correctly there.  This could be another A/B test by the Stack Exchange folks.

Comment: Seems network-wide bug (again): [Reputation changes not visible in the achievement box (again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315892)

Comment: Me too. In addition, the rep isn't correctly updated on the meta user page and many of the icons are wrong (the displacements don't correspond to the vertical icons image.)

Comment: The achievement menu seems to be up again. At least my reputation is now shown correctly.

Comment: @BDL Yeah I got the delayed updates too, it's up and running again.

Comment: Had the same thing yesterday. Things were back to normal after a couple of hours.

Comment: For various updates like rep network badges, achievements or badges, it is IMHO not a bug (but maybe a missing feature ;) ) to have to wait some hours for everything to propagate. Usually, I give it a day before worrying / grumbling alone before my screen.